# adding two iterative values into an update query asp-classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm sure my error here is simple

I have a 2d Array from my sqlDB on a single column

```
myList = rs.GetRows()
```

I have html page with inputs based on the length of my array. :

```
<input type="number" name="actual">
```

now, what I'm trying to do is build a unique SQL update query where the actual column matches the unique_id column

lets assume we have only two variables on my list.

```
for each x in my list
 response.write(x)
1,
2
```

and there are only two inputs as the inputs are generated by the unique ID

```
for inputs in response.form("actual")
 response.write(inputs)
55,
66
```

now, I want to combine these to build my update query.

I've tried writing a double for loop but this generates an ID for every instance of the input so creating 4 variables instead of 2

```
 Unique ID, Input
    1 : 55
    1 : 66
    2 : 55
    2 : 66
```

what I would like is

```
1 : 55
2 : 66
```

is anyone able to help? I've been at this for hours. I'm not a coder or from a technical background and I'm knee deep in legacy systems and processes.

I'm sure a dictionary would be the way to go so I can generated a 1 for 1 relationship but I have no idea how to convert my inputs into a list then pass them into a dict.

html code to generate my table :

```
  <div class="container">
              <table id="table" class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                  <th scope="col" data-field="article">Unique ID</th>
                  <th scope="col" data-field="item">Item Name</th>
                  <th scope="col" data-field="quant">Quantity</th>
                  <th scope="col" data-field="act">Actual</th>
              </tr>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            </div>

           <%
           While not grs.eof
          %>
            <tr>
                <th><%=grs.fields("UniqueID")%></th>
                <th><%=grs.fields("itemName")%></th>
                <th><%=grs.fields("quant")%></th>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="actual" placeholder="<%=grs.fields("actual")%>" name="Actual">

            <%

            grs.movenext
            Wend
SQL update query goes here %>
```

Comment: How do you differentiate your inputs? By that I mean, where do your UniqueId's appear in your generated html?

Comment: they appear within a html table so, there is a `unique_id` with the input columns on its right. can post a screengrab if you like. (it's all generated within a while not EOF query)

Comment: Yep, seeing the resulting html code would be helpful.

Comment: Added it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, little thing here:

Your id can't be the same for every line, so do something like `id=actual_<%=grs.fields("UniqueID")%>`

You can try this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="actual_<%=grs.fields("UniqueID")%>" placeholder="<%=grs.fields("actual")%>" name="actual_<%=grs.fields("UniqueID")%>">
```

And then in your loop:

```
for each inputs in request.form
   if left(inputs, 7) = "actual_" then
      myId = mid(inputs, 8)
      myValue = request.form("actual_" & myId)

      <your sql statement here>
   end if
next
```

(You'll have to add something to check the name of the input you're checking is at least 7 chars long or you'll get an error)

Comment: testing now! thanks Chris, my input is a 1 or 2 digit int so won't be longer than 7 chars!

Comment: I mean the name of the input (in my example actual_123). If you have any other input field in the form with a name like "short" (5 chars), the code above will fail. You could use `instr` instead of `left`

Comment: got it, few queries 1. when I use response.write on the code above I'm getting blanks 2. I think you forgot the each keyword before the for loop I added this in mine?

Comment: Yep, edited to add the missing each. I notice you don't have a value parameter in your input tag (placeholder isn't enough).

Comment: also I'm not very good with HTML but isn't `ID` for front end programming and `name` for server side / back end ?

Comment: You're using Classic ASP, so no!

Comment: got it working, I had to add the variable at the top into my name not ID and that sorted it out :) thanks buddy you are my hero.